# How to bin the a column almost equally based on the range in PySpark, on groupBy results?

Tags: python, pyspark, quantile

I have been trying hard to divide a column that I have into bins. I looked at pandas.qcut and pandas.cut and have understood this fairly. ( qcut will divide my population into equal number of bins and cut will divide my range into equal bins).

I understand that I need the functionality of cut in PySpark.

I experimented with approxQuantile, which takes a real long time in processing. I also experimented with QuantileDiscretizer ( which is similar to qcut, which gave me the same number of items in my output).

I am trying out Bucketizer, however looks like there's no straightaway method to apply this on a groupby/window output.

Is there any other way that I should look at in order to compute this?

[Applying Bucketizer to Spark dataframe after partitioning based on a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64938114/1930402)